# Ctrl+G in erl doesn't work

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, erlang, docker

I'm trying to interconnect erlang nodes, but entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> doesn not work:

```
Eshell V6.4.1  (abort with ^G)
1> ^G
Eshell V6.4.1  (abort with ^G)
1> ^G
Eshell V6.4.1  (abort with ^G)
1> ^G
Eshell V6.4.1  (abort with ^G)
```

any idea why this can happen? I was thinking about locale settings, changed it to UTF-8:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

any idea why this can happen? everything is being done inside docker containers.

Comment: Try start shell with `erl -boot start_sasl` if you see some error message providing any clue.

Comment: What OS and how are you starting erlang?

Comment: @JaniBaramidze please post your oslution to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem, needed export TERM=linux.